# What does spaghetti-history mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147389/1637673), I saw this sentance

> But this way a new dummy commit is added. If you want to avoid spaghetti-history you can rebase:

Google `spaghetti-history` only shows the history of spaghetti.
I think there may be two meanings in original context :

1. spaghetti is long -> tedious , we want to avoid long  tedious thing.
2. the history of spaghetti is long -> tedious , we want to avoid long  tedious thing.

Or is this `spaghetti-history` from some famous story/allusion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to the right answer!  In programming, the word *spaghetti* is used to refer to things that are complicated and tangled and do not follow an obvious straight line from one place to another.  Think of what a bowl of spaghetti looks like: all of the strands criss-cross each other and wind around, and you can't tell where one strand begins and ends.

[image]

So *spaghetti history* would mean **history that is complicated and tangled and unclear**.

(And it should really be written "spaghetti history", not "spaghetti-history", because in English we don't usually put a dash between two nouns when we're using one of them as an adjective.)

References:

https://www.techopedia.com/definition/9476/spaghetti-code